# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el número de pagina al imprimir una pagina web?

Tags: css

tengo la siguiente cabecera en cada hoja al imprimir  una pagina web
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber como puedo mostrar el el numero de pagina, se que en css a través del selector  `@page`
tengo acceso al contenido de las paginas, pero no se como realizar lo que quiero

Comment: Te refieres a esto ? -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346309/como-poner-un-numero-de-pagina-al-imprimir-con-css-en-html

Comment: Lo que me estas señalando lo entiendo, pero en mi caso no aplica ya que utilizo una tabla con thead y tfoot para el encabezado y el pie de pagina, y esto lo hago una sola vez, por lo tanto  no tengo un elemento para contar el numero de paginas